# neo4j-server.properties missing and unable to start neo4j

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

i followed the link http://debian.neo4j.org/ for intalling neo4j. But when i checked /etc/neo4j there is only 2 files named neo4j.conf and neo4j-wrapper.conf. There is no neo4j-server.properties. And i am unable to start neo4j using 
sudo service neo4j-service start
it retuns,
Failed to start neo4j-service.service: Unit neo4j-service.service not found.
Is there ay solution?

Comment: That's what they're called in Neo4j 3. Have you read the manual? http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#linux-installation

Answer (score 6):

The `neo4j-service` service is no longer created in the Neo4j 3.0 Debian package. Instead there is a symlink to the `neo4j` binary in `/usr/local/bin` so you can simply use `neo4j start`, `neo4j stop` and `neo4j restart` to start and stop Neo4j.

As noted in [the manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#linux-installation) the configuration files in Neo4j 3.0 have been consolidated and renamed.

Comment: Thanks williams.I tried this.But when i run the command neo4j start it doesn't return anything. And i thought there is something error in my installation and i refer other sites for starting neo4j.

Answer (score 2):

As William explained, the Debian package for Neo4j 3.0 and above no longer creates a service by the name of neo4j-service.

You can use the following commands

```
service neo4j start -> starts the neo4j database service
service neo4j stop  -> stops the neo4j database service
service neo4j status -> displays the status of the neo4j database service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue using *neo4j start* as well. For me the issue was in Centos 7, but I resolved it with:

 
*./bin/neo4j start*